# How can I write a "definition" like this?

Tags: theorems, proof-package, newtheorem, definition

[image]The theorem of the picture is written in bold, I mean: **Theorem 1.2 (Pythagorean theorem)**. I want to write a definition with that format. Also, it would be better if it's written with small capitals. Beforehand, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`amsthm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package. It lets you do things like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}

    \begin{defn}[\scshape Definition]
        A definition is a definition.
    \end{defn}

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the appearance, you can either use one of the three predefined theorem styles in `amsthm`, or use `\newtheoremstyle` to create your own one like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtheoremstyle{mijail}
    {3pt}
    {3pt}
    {\itshape}
    {}
    {\bfseries}
    {}
    {.5em}
    {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \thmnote{(\scshape #3)}}

\theoremstyle{mijail}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}

    \begin{defn}[Definition]
        A definition is a definition.
    \end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Note that your standard font might not include bold small caps, hence the use of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I wanted